# argv Memory Allocation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, swi-prolog

I was wondering if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong that I get this Unhandled Exception error message:

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000c.
```

with a green pointer pointing at my first Prolog code (fid_t):

Here is my header file:

```
class UserTaskProlog
{
  public:
             UserTaskProlog( ArRobot* r );
             ~UserTaskProlog( );
  protected:
             int cycles;
             char* argv[ 1 ];
             term_t tf;
             term_t tx;
             term_t goal_term;
             functor_t goal_functor;
             ArRobot* robot;
             void logTask( );
};
```

And here is my main code:

```
UserTaskProlog::UserTaskProlog( ArRobot* r ) : robot( r ), robotTaskFunc( this, &UserTaskProlog::logTask )
{
  cycles = 0;
  argv[ 0 ] = "libpl.dll";
  argv[ 1 ] = NULL;
  PL_initialise( 1, argv );
  PlCall( "consult( 'myPrologFile.pl' )" );
  robot->addSensorInterpTask( "UserTaskProlog", 50, &robotTaskFunc );
}

UserTaskProlog::~UserTaskProlog( )
{
  robot->remSensorInterpTask( &robotTaskFunc );
}

void UserTaskProlog::logTask( )
{
  cycles++;

  fid_t fid = PL_open_foreign_frame( );

    tf = PL_new_term_ref( );
    PL_put_integer( tf, 5 );
    tx = PL_new_term_ref( );
    goal_term = PL_new_term_ref( );
    goal_functor = PL_new_functor( PL_new_atom( "factorial" ), 2 );
    PL_cons_functor( goal_term, goal_functor, tf, tx );
    int fact;
    if ( PL_call( goal_term, NULL ) )
    {
      PL_get_integer( tx, &fact );
      cout << fact << endl;
    }

  PL_discard_foreign_frame( fid );

}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  ArRobot robot;
  ArArgumentParser argParser( &argc, argv );
  UserTaskProlog talk( &robot );
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part here is nasty:

```
char** argv;
argv[ 0 ] = "libpl.dll";
argv[ 1 ] = NULL;
```

`argv` is a dangling pointer - no storage has been allocated. Change it to this:

```
char* argv[2];
argv[ 0 ] = "libpl.dll";
argv[ 1 ] = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  
That was a valid point.  
However, it didn't resolve the situation.  
I even commented out  argv[0]="libpl.dll";  to no avail.  
I still get the same error message, which apparently points to some null pointer issue...

Comment: @Joshua: you should probably edit your question so that it has the latest version of the code (with the argv problem fixed)

Comment: The assignment at   
    `argv[ 1 ] = NULL;`  
means argv should be allocated to at least two elements:  
    `char* argv[2];`

Comment: @Frayser: good catch - the argv[1] assignment wasn't present in the original question (it got added later) - I've now updated my answer to match the current version of the posted code.